# How to map db volume in azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-registry

I am trying to host a multi container app (web api+ postgres db)  in azure using azure container registry as image source.

This is the docker compose file I am using:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerapi:
    image: test.azurecr.io/pgdemo:1
    ports:
      - "1985:80"   

  postgresimage:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "bloguser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "bloguser"
      POSTGRES_DB: "blogdb"
    volumes:
      - $./dbscripts/seed.sql :/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
   db-data:
      driver: local
```

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/net-core-web-api-with-docker-compose-postgresql-and-ef-core-21f47351224f) to develop this application and everything went well in local environment. It seems the `volumes` section is not proper in docker-compose file. I tried replacing `.` with `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME` and still the seed scripts are ignored it seems from azure conatainer logs:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.279183157Z       Failed executing DbCommand (41ms)
>   [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.279189958Z       SELECT b.id, b.title,
>   b.description 2019-06-18T07:00:20.279193958Z       FROM blog AS b
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298436041Z       WHERE STRPOS(b.title, 'Title') >
>   0 2019-06-18T07:00:20.298452842Z Npgsql.PostgresException
>   (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "blog" does not exist
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298457842Z    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298462242Z --- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown --- 2019-06-18T07:00:20.298466242Z
>   at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298478543Z --- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown --- 2019-06-18T07:00:20.298482943Z
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean
>   isConsuming) 2019-06-18T07:00:20.298486743Z    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() 2019-06-18T07:00:20.298490643Z
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior,
>   Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298494543Z    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298498343Z    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   2019-06-18T07:00:20.298502143Z    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)

Is it the right way to add data volumes in azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add data volume for the Web App for Container in Azure, you need to mount the path in the volume like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerapi:
    image: test.azurecr.io/pgdemo:1
    ports:
      - "1985:80"   

  postgresimage:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "bloguser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "bloguser"
      POSTGRES_DB: "blogdb"
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbscripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
   db-data:
      driver: local
```

And then set the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `True`. Remember, it just adds the persisting volume. So you need to copy file seed.sql to the path through FTP/FTPS. For more details, see [Add persistent storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app#add-persistent-storage).

Comment: Thank you @charles.  I have set WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE as True and used ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} in docker-compose file. Why should I copy the seed.sql file explicitly? It would be part of the image "dockerapi" right? And I am unable to see the storage anywhere in azure portal as well. How to copy the file through ftp/ftps ?

Comment: @Sharun It just creates persistent storage for you, will not create the file for you. And it will overwrite the volume inside the web app. Actually, you can see the persistent storage in the kudu of the web app. The `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}` means the path `/home` in the kudu.

Comment: I checked kudu and could find that the seed file is already there in dbscripts folder ( it was part of the "dockerapi " image which I pushed to the azure registry earlier)

Comment: I deleted the app and recreated it from the scratch, and now I am getting this error in the azure log : `"2019-06-19T08:17:27.256619560Z /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
2019-06-19T08:17:27.445715502Z psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql:0: could not read from input file: Is a directory`

Comment: @Sharun The error shows the seed.sql is just a directory, not a file. Check in the kudu.

Comment: yes, you are right. It seems the file is not there in the Dbscripts folder. But how can I copy the file to the folder? I am even not able to manually add contents to a file from bash in kudu.

Comment: @Sharun You can use the ftp/ftps to upload the files. In the web app dashboard, you can find the ftp/ftps address and user name, and you can see the credentials in the deployment credentials panel in the left.